# How would I make a static screen effect like a tv would have?

Tags: java, effects, pixel

I want to make an effect that would look like the [static on a old tv](http://media.giphy.com/media/xaMg6NGwH2fFS/giphy.gif)

I want it so it's moving and I'd rather not use multiple premade images to make the effect. How would I get this kind of effect with mono colors (black and white) lasting a period of about 3-5 seconds?

Comment: Really, why -1? I cannot find this kind of question anywhere and it seems useful if people want to make a horror type of game.

Comment: you might be getting the -1's because you didn't tell us what you tried, why it didn't work, etc.  "too general" is the leading close reason...

Comment: Also have a look at javax.swing.Timer

Comment: @JohnGardner I didn't try anything cus I had no idea where to start which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `java.awt.Canvas` class.

Override the paint method in your canvas class, and than use this code to generate static:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y++){
            int col = (int)(Math.round(Math.random()*100)%50);
            if(Math.random() > 0.5){
                col = 255 - col;
            }
            g.setColor(new Color(col, col, col);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

What this is essentially doing is rendering a w*h grid is pixels, each with a value of 50 max for r, g, and b color values. This will make a grainy black-gray texture, and can be adapted to other grid matricies.

**EDIT:**

1. Changed from `Canvas` to `JPanel`, with `paintComponent` method.
2. Made shade brighter or lighter based on random chance.

Comment: I can't use Canvas since all my repaints are on JPanels, also I've had trouble with Canvas's in the past.

Comment: I've got it to work on JPanel but isn't there a way to make it black and white rather than black and grey?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my answer. For future reference, please add things like this in your question, as it would be useful for those answering it.

Comment: Do you want black and white, or shades of both?

Comment: Like normal tv static so I guess shades of both.

Comment: OK. I put that in the answer.

Comment: It's still only back and grey.

Comment: My bad! I set the color before rather than after.

Comment: Thank, also you should put a int cast on the `int col = (Math.round(Math.random()*100)%50);` and `g.setColor` is missing a ) at the end.

Comment: OK. Sorry about that, forgot about casting from double.

Comment: Huh? This is not what TV static looks like. For one thing, I remember TV static to be biased towards the extremes of black or white with few grey spots.

Comment: Is that not what this algorithm does?